# How to copy to clipboard 3 last lines from :messages

Tags: vim

If I use `:messages` vim command I get to pager like mode with vim log, where I cannot select lines without mouse (in some programs like neovim-qt I cant even use right-click menu (like in gnome terminal) to copy text)

how to copy 3 last lines?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can redirect the output of `:message` to the clipboard register (`@+`) or primary register (`@*`):

```
:redir @+
:3message
:redir END
```

See `:help :redir`, `:help :message`.

Comment: I tried `:3message` but it didn't work, `:3messages` works